# Can I drink beer on the paleo diet?

Tags: paleo-diet, alcohol

I'm pretty sure it's all in the question. Let's assume I'm talking about the standard kind of beer, you know, the kind I can buy in a pub (as you can tell, I don't know much about beer).

Comment: From the FAQ: on-topic includes "nutrition as it relates to exercise" and off-topic includes "nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children". To that list I would add, "what foods are Paleo".

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I think I joined the wrong SE then, and I apologize. Unfortunately, this SE seems to be the only that even remotely matches the concept of a place where I can ask questions on diets.. I guess I'm off to the meta again, huh..

Comment: Have you tried http://paleohacks.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Paleo framework starts from the perspective that most people will find that grains, legumes, dairy, being anti-social, getting no sunlight or exercise, and eating too many carbs for their exercise level will be problematic, for genetic and epigenetic reasons.

That being said, here's the Paleo test at its most bare:

```
 Does it cause you gastrointestinal distress? Are you sure?
```

That's really it.

Try abstaining from grains (like beer), legumes and dairy for thirty days. Then re-introduce these items one by one, and gauge your response. People are different. Some people can handle these items better than others.